# cannot align text next to image with proper intent

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

Hello i am trying to make an footer it have an image so i am not able to properly intent my webpage please help... I want to achieve something like this::

CodePen link :https://codepen.io/Sherrinford03/pen/yGKaQb

[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oNWv.jpg)

[how far i have come](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MPY5.jpg)

```
<div class="footer">
        <div class="part">
            <div class="body_of_part">
            <img src="images/brochure.jpg" align="bottom">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
            <div class="body_of_part">
            <span class="Title_of_departments">ADDRESS</span>
            <span class="Body_of_cap">SOMEADD</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
            <div class="body_of_part">
            <span class="Title_of_departments">Contact us</span>
            <span class="Body_of_cap">
                Email<br>
                SOMEMAIL
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

...CSS

```
.footer{
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    margin:20vh 0vw 0 0 ;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    background: #222222;
}
.part img{
    vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
    width: 20vw;
}
.footer .part{ 
    height: 40vh;
    border-left: 1px solid #353535;
    display: inline-block;
    width:20vw;
}
.part .Body_of_cap{
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Can u please help me ! i have been looking for a solution for about 2 hours ... PLease help!

Comment: Your code does not match your screen shot, but I think you need `.part {display:table-cell; margin-top:60px; vertical-align:top;}`

Comment: tried that its not working

Comment: Then provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @MrLister i have added the codepen link on the post .

Comment: I added the code I mentioned - https://codepen.io/MrLister/pen/aPYmrj?editors=1100 - and it seems to work here... apparently I'm misinterpreting how you want it to come out.

Comment: @MrLister it works fine without the full body but after adding the full body it doesnt works : https://codepen.io/Sherrinford03/pen/yGKaQb have a look please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove

```
inline-block
```

from

```
.footer .part{
```

and it should work

Comment: The text isnt moving up to the top

Comment: the text isn't moving up because you have a margin-top of 60px

Comment: can u please tell me the line no. so that i can solve it

Comment: my mistake, the padding is coming from line 155 in your css

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, I modifierd 3 css classes:

```
.footer{
     /*display: table;*/
     text-align: center;
     margin:20vh 0vw 0 0 ;
     padding:0 0 0 0;
     background: #222222;
     height: 300px
}
.footer .part{ 
     height: 40vh;
     border-left: 1px solid #353535;
     /*display: inline-block;*/
     width:20vw;
     /*display:table-cell; vertical-*/
     display: inline-block;
     align:top;
}

.Title_of_departments{
     display:block;
     font-family: "Sofachrome" !important;
     font-size: 20px;
     /*padding:20vh 0vh 5vh 0vh;*/
     text-align: center;
     color: #E50000;
  }
```

https://codepen.io/lolpez/pen/zyWoxL